# Stale ASP.NET temporary file cache?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, razor

I'm having some issues with a site caching outdated binary for razor views, I believe within the below directory.  I have the site configured to JIT compile these views rather than precompile them.  Could someone point me to some information, and help me understand the details around how views are cached and retrieved in ASP.NET MVC?  How does ASP.NET determine whether to fetch old views from cache vs recompiling?

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root

Comment: This is local dev, or on the prod webserver?

Comment: What makes you think it is binary caching rather than the web browser caching the content?

Comment: @mjwills prod web server and lower tiers. I know it's not client side because i've decompiled the dll's and seen that the binary representation is out of date. Also i have log entries which reference code that no longer exists in artifact.  And i've viewed the offending pages in incognito mode.